# How to fix a Tab as first tab on TPageControl and keep it showing while navigating on tabs?

Tags: delphi

I have this form:

[image]

Green arrow: Tab General, and I'd like to keep it always visible, but when the form is smaller than the tabs, TPageControl creates a navigator (the red arrow).

It's good, but I'd like to allow the user navigate but keep showing the possibility to click on the General Tab.

Example:

[image]

In this picture, I used the navigator and I can't see General Tab anymore.
I'd like to keep it as the first tab on the PageControl, like a "fixed column" in Excel for instance.

Comment: I think, that such behaviour is not possible with `TPageControl`, unfortunately. But maybe property `MultiLine` helps you. When this property is enabled, the tabs are visible all at once, ordered in multiple lines.

Comment: Multiline is a UI abomination. Don't do it!

Comment: What you plan to do won't look good. There's really. I good solution other than finding a way to avoid the navigator completely

Comment: It's a legacy system, thousands of screens with the same situations a lot of tabs and users must to navigate and them came back etc. I'd like to offer a fast solution, I don't have permission, people, time to change every form :/

Comment: Why not just put a TPanel above the PageControl with a 'Home' button that navigates back to to the first page?

Comment: @JohnEasley as I told before, this situations is because Im working with a legacy system and there are hundred of screens to change. I dont have the option to stop everything to change all the screens.

Comment: Nevertheless, John's idea is in principle a good one. You can use an intercept class and create a descendant of TPageControl that creates such a panel in its constructor. You could not expect any less work with any solution. Unfortunately the problem is that not all tabs are the same width, so it would not look good in practice as part of the second tab would always be hidden.

Comment: @RodrigoFariasRezino: As Rene says, I don't think this is possible. I wanted to achieve the same with my neTabControl but I couldn't using native controls. I had to come up with a different design, which in your case would require you to change all the control--and as you said, you can't do this.

What you could do is to change the Left arrow behavior, so when one clicks on it, the General tab gets the focus. But in any case, you would have to change all the controls. I think your situation doesn't give you much choices

Comment: If you make a replacement page control then you could change all of the forms using an Interposer class. Provided you maintain compatibility.

Comment: Yes, I'm digging deep to find some solution, but I read the SysTabControl32 api, and we don't have so much option about it. The navigator is invisible for us, so I don't have ways to intercept it's actions to try to do something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I didn't found a way to fix the tab! But I solved my problem creating a custom page control based on our discussion on this thread.

[image]
[image]
[image]
You can [check it here](https://github.com/rfrezino/SearchTabControl)

Comment: Just to make sense about our discussion. In my case the company that I work for already used a TPageControl component descendant, so I odd the source to it class and I can use it without the necessity to change all the screens.

Comment: I'll not accept my answer as the right answer because it not solve the question I did. I'll just let it here as an option...